# Updating from the old Realm to Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm trying to upgrade to the newest version of Realm from 0.91, but I keep getting all sorts of different errors. I have a feeling that this is because there are still leftovers from this previous version of Realm and Realm Swift now has a completely different installation process. Has anyone done this update and can give some advice here? I'm able to get Realm Obj-c 0.92 working, but I would rather use the Swift specific version if I had the choice.

Thanks.

Comment: What errors in particular are you seeing?

Comment: @segiddins I tried multiple times, so I received a few different errors. The two main ones were "No such module Realm" and "rlmresults does not have a member named generator." These appeared separately, on two different attempts to upgrade. 

Oh, and I'm using the Dynamic Framework installation, in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: Well RealmSwift only has a dynamic framework, and RealmSwift uses the Results class, instead of RLMResults.

Comment: I was getting that error specifically on the line 
   
        `for obj in sampleRealm.allObjects(){ //For every object in the realm
                println(obj.description)        //Print the whole object
            }`


So how would this specific line be different? Am I no longer calling allObjects?

Comment: To use Realm Swift, you'll likely want to remove Realm Objective-C from your existing project. As a rule of thumb, if you see an `RLM`-prefixed type in your code, that's referring to Realm Objective-C and not Swift. You'll find an overview of the Swift APIs here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/. In your case, `RLMObject.allObjects()` would become `Realm().objects(MyObjectType)`.

Comment: Thanks, I think that might have been my issue here. I'll give it another try and report back if I have any continued issues.